# Disable translation of Zend_Navigation elements

Tags: zend-framework, internationalization, menu, translation, zend-navigation

Is there any easy way to disable translation of some of the Zend Navigation elements?
e.g. in this case

```
$page = new Zend_Navigation_Page_Mvc(
    array(
        'label' => $blogPost->alreadyTranslatedTitleFromDb
        // ... 
    )
);

$container->addPage($page);
```

Now, when I use:

```
$page->getLabel();
```

the label is translated twice. The same for breadcrumbs, sitemaps etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a patch with unit tests for this:

- http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-10948

Answer (score 0):

If you want only some specific elements to be disabled, i think that only way is to use a partial view script and create your own logic for the menu.

You may add custom properties to the pages. Example: add a property ***doNotTranslate*** and in your view script check for this property to know if element should be translated or not.

More info about partial view script is available at http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.navigation.menu